# I have to restart my Java socket connection for multiple file transfer

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I have created a small server client program for Android. It is working like charm except one thing. First session of file transfer works without any problem, but when I try to send another file, I can't do it without restarting my socket connection. I wanted to achieve this:
1. Start Android server
2. Connect remote client
3. Transfer as many files as one wishes in the same session (without having to restart server and reconnecting client)
How can it be done? Any help would be appreciated!
Here's my code snippet:
Server side methods:

```
public void initializeServer() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  registerLog("Server started successfully at: "+ getLocalIpAddress());
                  registerLog("Listening on port: 4444");
                  registerLog("Waiting for client request . . .");
              }
            });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Listen failed", "Couldn't listen to port 4444");
    }

    try {
           socket = serverSocket.accept();
           runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      registerLog("Client connected: "+socket.getInetAddress());
                  }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Acceptance failed", "Couldn't accept client socket connection");
    }
}
```

Sending file to client:

```
public void sendFileDOS() throws FileNotFoundException {
    runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              registerLog("Sending. . . Please wait. . .");
          }
        });
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final File myFile= new File(filePath); //sdcard/DCIM.JPG
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    try {
        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        //Sending file name and file size to the server  
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);     
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());     
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);     
        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);     
        dos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              long estimatedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
              registerLog("File successfully sent");
              registerLog("File size: "+myFile.length()/1000+" KBytes");
              registerLog("Elapsed time: "+estimatedTime+" sec. (approx)");
              registerLog("Server stopped. Please restart for another session.");
          }
        });
}
```

Client side (running on PC):

```
public class myFileClient {
final static String servAdd="10.142.198.127";
static String filename=null;
static Socket socket = null;
static Boolean flag=true;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    initializeClient();
    receiveDOS();       
}
public static void initializeClient () throws IOException {
    InetAddress serverIP=InetAddress.getByName(servAdd);
    socket=new Socket(serverIP, 4444);
}
public static void receiveDOS() {
    int bytesRead;
    InputStream in;
    int bufferSize=0;

    try {
        bufferSize=socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        in=socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        System.out.println(fileName);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("//home//evinish//Documents//Android//Received files//"+ fileName);
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while (size > 0
                && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                        (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flushing just after

```
output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

If this still doesn't work I found mine server/client works best with objectoutputstreams that you use in the the following way.

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

// always call flush and reset after sending anything
oos.writeObject(server.getPartyMembersNames());
oos.flush();
oos.reset();

YourObject blah = (YourObject) ois.readObject();
```